# whats difference between xml query with sql query?

Tags: reporting-services, xml, reports, reporting

I need to know advantages and disadvantages XML query and SQL query for SharePoint report.when we have large data which one has best performance? which one is faster?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience using XML query to create reports but a little using SQL query. So, from my unknowledge, I think the latter will be more effective and will have a better performance because of, in the end, XML queries would have to be translated into SQL queries in order to work, right? I suppose that SQL language is the basic and primary language SSRS will understand so, everything that will be made on top of SSRS will be translated to SQL.

[XML Query syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/xml-query-syntax-for-xml-report-data-ssrs)

[Query Design Tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/query-design-tools-ssrs)

Comment: It's even simpler than that if the data is in a database use SQL, if it's in an XML document use XML They are totally separate,